# Why is BigQuery wrapping/rounding the max value for timestamp?

Tags: google-bigquery

According to the official [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#timestamp_type), BigQuery supports the range `0001-01-01 00:00:00 to 9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999 UTC` for the `Timestamp` type. However, when we try to set a value to `9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999Z`, BigQuery returns `10000-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  min_timestamp,
  max_timestamp,
  UNIX_MICROS(min_timestamp) AS min_unix_micros,
  UNIX_MICROS(max_timestamp) AS max_unix_micros
FROM (
  SELECT
    TIMESTAMP '0001-01-01 00:00:00.000000Z' AS min_timestamp,
    TIMESTAMP '9999-12-31 23:59:58.999999Z' AS max_timestamp
);
```

Is this a bug, or are we doing something wrong? The use case is to end-date records, a common practice across other DW/DBs.

Comment: It behaves quite strangely. These are my results:
select timestamp('0001-01-01 00:00:00.000000Z'); --> 0001-01-03 00:00:00.000000
select timestamp('0001-01-01'); --> 0001-01-03 00:00:00.000000

Comment: It seems the issue is connected with the Simba driver. In my case I am using the version 1.2.16. When I try the same queries on the web the results are correct.

Comment: Progress of the issue can be now found in the public issue tracker from Google (at least for the minimum timestamp).
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/214303737